# array item losing value when input checked

Tags: javascript, jquery, arrays, loops

Why is it that I get the proper value of "item" in the first loop, but in the each loop I get undefined? How do I keep the value of the "item"?

Here's the code:

```
for (item in products_custom){
    console.log(item);
    $("input:checked").each(function(){
        console.log(item);
    });
}
```

Thanks a lot for your help.

Comment: this is the exact code you're running?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're not closing your `each` call properly, so if that were your real code, it would give a syntax error.  It should be:

```
for (var item in products_custom){
    console.log(item);
    $("input:checked").each(function(){
        console.log(item);
    });
}
```

Note we use `var` to avoid a global.  However, neither of these issues fit with the problem you describe, and it works ([jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/TSEJL/)) after fixing the syntax errors.

Comment: sorry, in the real code, the each call is closed. This is just a typo when trying to simplify the code. Edited in the OP

Comment: @donkapone, there is still an extra right paren.  Please only post code you've tested yourself.